# syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '(' в list (php)

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
<?php
list(filename, name, author, material, scale, date, museum, city, notation) = $_POST;
echo author;
```

Появляется ошибка

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '(' in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\csv.php on line 2

Почему?

Comment: Ну наверное потому что переменная через $ пишется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знак `$` перед переменными не забывайте.

```
<?php
list($filename, $name, $author, $material, $scale, $date, $museum, $city, $notation) = $_POST;
echo $author;
```

Comment: Ох, такая нелепая ошибка. Спасибо!